# Get courses list with udemy api

Tags: javascript, php, api, curl

Im trying to reach udemy courses list with their affiliate API and PHP.

I can get data without problem if i dont use json_decode'. When i use json_decode im getting this error.

> 'SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data'

```
function getcourse($id)
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $url = "https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/$id?fields[course]=@all";
    //  Initiate curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Disable SSL verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    // Will return the response, if false it print the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    // Execute
    $c_id = base64_encode('myclientid');
    $c_sid = base64_encode('myclientsecretid');

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-Udemy-Client-Id: '.$c_id.'','X-Udemy-Client-Secret: '.$c_sid.'',"Authorization: base64 encoded value of client-id:client-secret","Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
    echo curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    // Closing
    curl_close($ch);


    $result = json_decode($result);
    return $result; 
}


$cdetail = getcourse(120042);
print_r($cdetail);
```

Comment: Thats a javascript error not a php one...

Comment: Start your debugging by outputting a simple `echo $result;` then show us what you get

Comment: 'Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /index.php on line 31' which targets 'echo $result;'

Comment: Now put the `echo $result;` **directly after this line** `$result=curl_exec($ch); echo $result;`

Comment: @TugceAksoz You have to echo it *before* the json_decode otherwise it becomes an object...

Comment: It would be helpful to see the javascript code the error is pointing to.

Comment: No additional error expect JSON Parse warning. Still i can see udemy course informations on data tab.

Comment: @RiggsFolly ' unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 10235 of the JSON data'

Comment: Please POST the output of `echo $result` written in the right place in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get any error running your code.
You're getting this error

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data'

Because you're using "header('Content-Type: application/json');", and you're probably using Firefox, it will think all content is json and it will verify if there is anything wrong with it.

Comment "header('Content-Type: application/json');" and you'll get your data.

Comment: Yes its a lot better now!